# Adjusting image container not scaling

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

I have a main container `projects-container` and then two children containers `.project-block` and `like-work`. I added in scaling code to my image in order for it to resize the width and height to keep the correct proportions. This is causing two seperate issues. The first issue is my `like-work` container is not even visible on the page anymore ..... see it live [here](http://optimumwebdesigns.com/work) . It shows on the snippet, but not on the page.

Secondly I cannot figure out how to get the `project-block-banner` to stay hidden with adjusting height with doing `display:none` and then `display-block` on hover. Before when I had set height, it would be hidden under the image, due to the overflow:hidden` and then slide up on hover. Now it just plops up into place instead of transitioning.

Does anyone know what I can do for these two issues? I'm not sure if my image resizing is the root for all of this and if so, is there a better way to resize the image?

```js
$('.project-block img').addClass(function() {
  return (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
});
```

```css
#projects-container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.project-block {
  width: 33.33333333333333333333333333%;
  height: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mobile {
  display: none;
}
.project-block img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
  transition-duration: .7s;
  position: relative;
}
.project-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.project-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
.project-block img:hover {
  transform: translate(0, -65px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -65px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
  transition-duration: .7s;
}
.project-block-banner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  bottom: -.00000000000001;
  background: #00a16d;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  display: none;
}
.project-block-banner-container {
  padding: 40px 50px;
}
.project-block-banner-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
} 
.project-block img:hover + .project-block-banner {
  transform: translate(0, -150px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -150px);
  -webkit-transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  display: block;
}
.project-block-banner-name, .project-block-banner-description {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.project-block-banner-name {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.project-block-banner-description {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

/*---Like Work----*/
#like-work {
  background: #0085a1;
  width: 66.66666666666666666666%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60%;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
#like-work-container {
  padding: 0 100px;
}
#like-title, #like-title2, #like-links {
  color: #FFF;
}
#like-title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
#like-title2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}
#like-links a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#like-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#like-links-button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  color: #FFF;
}
#like-links-button:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #0085a1;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projects-container">
  <div class="project-block">
    <a href="projects/eslich-wrecking"><img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/eslich.jpg" alt="" class="desktop"><div class="project-block-banner">
      <div class="project-block-banner-container">
        <div class="project-block-banner-name">fgds gfdsgfds</div>
          <div class="project-block-banner-description">gfdgs gfdsg fgsgsg</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="like-work">
    <div id="like-work-container" class="total-center">
    <div id="like-title">gfdg dfsg sdfg sdg</div>
    <div id="like-title2">gfd gfds gfds gfsd gfds fd</div>
    <div id="like-links"><a href="discuss-project"><span id="like-links-button">DISCUSS DESIGN PROJECT</span></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm checking the live version you need to wrap your project-block-banner in the figcaption as well.

Comment: Actually you dont need to use project-block-banner css anymore in my demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Here's an approach you could try, wrap your image and text blocks in a figure tag and a figcaption respectively.

I changed the following:

1. Hover effect from `display: none; display:block;` to
   `opacity: 0; opacity: 1;`
2. `transform(x,y)` for `transformY(value)` since you are just
   transforming Y axis
3. Vendor prefixes order, always having the main css property
   after the vendors.

---

**PLAYGROUND:**:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruiz/ppskfpnx/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
*::after,
*::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#projects-container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.project-block {
  width: 33.33333333333333333333333333%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mobile {
  display: none;
}

.project-block img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .7s;
  transition-duration: .7s;
  position: relative;
}

.project-block figure:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-65px);
  transform: translateY(-65px);
}

.project-block a {
  display: block;
}

.project-block figure {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.project-block figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #00a16d;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.project-block figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.1s;
}

.project-block-banner-container {
  padding: 40px 50px;
}

.project-block-banner-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.project-block-banner-name,
.project-block-banner-description {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.project-block-banner-name {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.project-block-banner-description {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}


/*---Like Work----*/

#like-work {
  background: #0085a1;
  width: 66.66666666666666666666%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#like-work-container {
}

#like-title,
#like-title2,
#like-links {
  color: #FFF;
}

#like-title {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

#like-title2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  margin-bottom: 65px;
}

#like-links a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

#like-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#like-links-button {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  color: #FFF;
}

#like-links-button:hover {
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #0085a1;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
}

.total-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="projects-container">
  <div class="project-block">
    <a href="projects/eslich-wrecking">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/work/eslich.jpg" alt="" class="desktop">
        <figcaption>
          <div class="project-block-banner">
            <div class="project-block-banner-container">
              <div class="project-block-banner-name">fgds gfdsgfds</div>
              <div class="project-block-banner-description">gfdgs gfdsg fgsgsg</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="like-work">
    <div id="like-work-container" class="total-center">
      <div id="like-title">gfdg dfsg sdfg sdg</div>
      <div id="like-title2">gfd gfds gfds gfsd gfds fd</div>
      <div id="like-links"><a href="discuss-project"><span id="like-links-button">DISCUSS DESIGN PROJECT</span></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well the transition works, but it also worked before I made changes to the container and gave it `height:auto`. The main part of my question is that the image needs to scale, and that the `like-work` container is not showing anymore. With your code my image isn't even 33.33% width.

Comment: There's a general layout problem then, I'll work on that, will edit soon.

Comment: I have editted my answer, changing some layout format. I recommend using bootstrap or some framework that will help you a lot creating your layout. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: Alright, the like-work box is back, but the image still won't scale. I don't know what to do for this.

Comment: The image should have height: auto;. At one point, in small devices viewport you'll need to change the width of each block using media queries. From 33.333% and 66.666% to 100%.

Comment: It does have `height: auto` ?

Comment: It seems like it caps off at a certain height and doesn't get to the full width of 33.33%

Comment: In my browser it's always displaying full width of 33.33%. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I'm using Chrome too. The project-box is 33%, but not the image. What size monitor are you on?

Comment: Oh okay the image is 490px and in my monitor 33.33% sets the image about 450. Try using min-width: 100%;

Comment: Awesome! What would you recommend to do when the screen size gets in the 1000-1200px size? I ideally want the image to be around 33% height of the page at that size.